# VS C# Localization

Tags: c#, winforms

Been a while since I have localized a WinForm project.

Must be missing something really basic.

Made a Hello World Winform project (VS2008) to refresh myself.

(Production project is in VS2013)

All the documentation I find says that the form has a localizable property which needs to be set to true.

But I can't find it.

(I want to use localized resx files for each form in the production project to set the Text of controls. I can create the resx files but the forms are ignoring them.)

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that property in Properties window in VS2013:

[image]

and in VS2008:

[image]

Comment: I am an idiot. Trying to view properties by clicking the form in the solution window. Result being file properties. Too much coffee and not enough sleep. thanks.